# Access environment variable from java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, environment-variables

I would like to know if there is any way I can access an environment variable from a java servlet. I know that I can pass params to the servlet using web.xml but I need to pass some value at run-time.

The requirement is something like this -

A non-web based app running at the server side sets some value (environment variable) and it has to be accessed during a web session (from the servlet). I am using apache web server.

I am new to web based programming, so forgive me if I am asking something silly/stupid.

Comment: Maybe you want to use databases.

Comment: What if the application doesn't use a database? What if you need to get a users settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to retrieve os environment variable use System.getenv() Method.

```
public static Map<String,String> getenv()
```

Returns an unmodifiable string map view of the current system environment. The environment is a system-dependent mapping from names to values which is passed from parent to child processes.

Answer (score 6):

Use [System.getenv()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()), available since JDK 5.